# Exclude Empty Rows & Retain Destination Formatting while Merging Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I customized Merging multiple Sheets of Data code from this site. I achieve a result with critical issues.

1. Empty Rows from the defined Range are being copied too. Tried avoiding them by tweaking RDB_Last function.
2. Unable to retain the Destination Formatting. Trying to use `If PasteAsValues = True Then`.

**Below is the Code**

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim FirstCell As String
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim myFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
MyPath = "C:\Users\zatin.dharmapuri\Desktop\3. 2018\Raw Data Month wise\Jan-2018"

' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
' in the search folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve myFiles(1 To FNum)
    myFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

' Set various application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Set the sheet name for the data to be copied to.
Set BaseWks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
rnum = 1

' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(myFiles) To UBound(myFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & myFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next

            'Change this range to fit your own needs.
            With mybook.Worksheets("Defect Analysis Reports")
               Set sourceRange = .Range("A5:J104")
            End With

                'FirstCell = "A5"
                'Set sourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(1, .Row))
                ' Test if the row of the last cell is equal to or greater than the row of the first cell.
                'If RDB_Last(1, .Row) < .Range(FirstCell).Row Then
                 '       Set sourceRange = Nothing
                  '  End If
                'End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                ' If source range uses all columns then
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Copy the file name in column A.
                    With sourceRange
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = myFiles(FNum)
                    End With

                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With Sourcesheet.Range("A5:J104").Value = 
                    DestinationSheet.Range("A5:J104").Value
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next FNum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If
ExitTheSub:
' Restore the application properties.

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
MsgBox "All Data has been merged successfully"
End Sub
```

I'm a beginner in VBA.

Comment: Instead of copying, try `Sourcesheet.Range("A1:D10").Value = DestinationSheet.Range("A1:D10").Value` (make sure both ranges are the same size). That should help with the formatting issue.

Comment: You are better off editing your question.

Comment: I edited the Code in my Question with what you suggested. But as I said it throws a Runtime Error : Object Required. Probably, I did not understand how to place your suggestion in my code.

Comment: Change `With Sourcesheet.Range("A5:J104").Value = DestinationSheet.Range("A5:J104").Value // End With` with `Sourcesheet.Range("A5:J104").Value = DestinationSheet.Range("A5:J104").Value` (no need for `with`)

Comment: Nice, Thanks for this. Looks like it did the magic. Formatting issue is out of way. Hope you crack the Empty row data issue too. Thanks again.